# Drawing rounded and colored owner draw buttons

Tags: windows, winapi, win32gui

In my windows application I am creating child button windows using CreateWindow() API. I am marking the style of buttons to be BS_OWNERDRAW, because I want to color the same and also want to make them rounded.
Here is my WM_DRAWITEM handling:

```
case WM_DRAWITEM:
            {
                RECT wndrect;
                pdi = (DRAWITEMSTRUCT*)lParam;

                GetWindowRect(pdi->hwndItem,&wndrect);
                hRgn =CreateRoundRectRgn(0,0,(wndrect.right-wndrect.left),(wndrect.bottom - wndrect.top),8,8);
                //SetWindowRgn(pdi->hwndItem,hRgn,TRUE);

                DrawColorButton(pdi->hDC,pdi->hwndItem,0/*Control id to be used*/,pdi->itemState,hRgn);
                DeleteObject(hRgn);
                return TRUE;
            }


void DrawColorButton(HDC hdc,HWND hWnd ,int iControlid/*unused*/,UINT iState, HRGN hRgn)
{
    RECT rect;

    int iWidth,iHeight;
    char str[100]={0};
    UINT oldAlign;
    GetClientRect(hWnd,&rect);
    GetWindowText(hWnd,str,sizeof(str));
    iWidth = rect.right - rect.left;
    iHeight = rect.bottom - rect.top;

    SetWindowRgn(hWnd,hRgn,TRUE);
    SetBkMode(hdc,TRANSPARENT);
    if(iState & ODS_DISABLED)
    {
        FillRect(hdc,&rect,CreateSolidBrush(GetSysColor(COLOR_INACTIVEBORDER)));
        SetTextColor(hdc,GetSysColor(COLOR_SCROLLBAR));
    }
    else
    {
        FillRect(hdc,&rect,CreateSolidBrush(RGB(100,225,255)));
        //FillRgn(hdc,hRgn,CreateSolidBrush(RGB(100,225,255)));
        //SetBkColor(hdc,RGB(100,225,255));
    }
}
```

I am getting very intermittent and strange behavior for this code. For the first time when the window opens all the buttons are properly rounded and colored. If I minimize and maximize the window , the rounded area vanishes and the entire button rectangle is filled with color. It seems to me that FillRect() API is causing the problem because commenting that I can see the rounded shapes(though colorless) consistently on the UI. I tried other Api's like FillRgn() and SetBkColor() but none of them fill any color to the region.

Has WM_COLORBTN got something to do with it? I did not handle that in my code as I will not be able to get the state directly in that case. Neither did I feel it necessary if I am doing WM_DRAWITEM. Thoughts?

Comment: At least one of the problems is that you are not painting the part of the window that is outside the rounded rectangle.  It will have an arbitrary color, whatever pixels were left in the video adapter.  Calling SetWindowRgn() is a good way to give a window a shape.  But do so in your init code, not the painting code.

Comment: Okay, but I have to do it under DRAWITEM only as there are a number of owner draw controls and I get there sizes at drawitem call only. The sizes are necessary to create the window region.

Comment: @user1624807: like Hans said, assign the region to a button at the time you **create** the button, not when you are **painting** the button. You know the size of the button since you have to give that info to `CreateWindow/Ex()` anyway. The **painting** code can then use `GetWindowRgn()` instead.

Comment: Thanks I will try it out and let you know meanwhile I found a work around to this.